# How to know which screen is focused at screen level in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to know how I could retrieve the information about which tab is focused at a screen level with React Navigation when using `createBottomTabNavigator`. With `focused`, it's possible to know if the tab is focused or not but if not we don't know which one is focused.
A pseudo code of my need would be like something like this (currentRoute doesn't exist):

```
 Homepage: {
    screen: HomeNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        if (focused) {
          return <Icon source={homeLogoOn} />
        } else {
          if (currentRoute === 'Me') {
            return <Icon source={homeLogoOffLeft} />
          } else if (currentRoute === 'MyFriends') {
            return <Icon source={homeLogoOffRight} />
          }
        }
      },
      tabBarLabel: <View />,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

react-navigation exposes an HOC to know if the current screen is focussed.

You can check the docs about it here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html

Comment: My problem is not to know if the screen is focused or not, I want to know which screen is focused

Comment: I don't think there's a direct call you can do in react-navigation to know which screen is focussed. The only thing is to add an eventListener inside every screen and do a setParams telling which screen is active